# Is it possible to store cookies in an encrypted SQLite database?

Tags: ios, sqlite, cookies

My question is that is it possible to store cookies in an encrypted SQLite database instead of cookies.binarycookies in case of iOS?

Comment: Where are the cookies from?

Comment: A mobile application use it.

Comment: this has nothing to do with computer programming.